# Can the perimeter of ellipse be expressed by a matrix exponential

Tags: geometry, matrix-exponential, elliptic-integrals

The perimeter of an ellipse is computed numerically by an infinite series. I want to know if this series can be expressed in a simpler way. For example, via matrix exponentials. Matrix exponentials are also numerically evaluated by infinite series, so it's not obviously impossible to me. Can we find a vector $v$, and matrix $A$ such that the perimeter $P$ of an ellipse follows the formula:
$$P = v^T e^A v$$

Can it be shown impossible? The matrix exponential is capable of encoding many things like geodesic paths on various manifolds so I have hope that it can express the perimeter of an ellipse as well. But it's not obvious to me how.

[Edit] $A$ and $v$ should be finite dimensional.

Comment: The only  link I see between ellipses and exponentials  is with 2D gaussian distributions whose level sets are ellipses. There is an interpretation of their **areas** as probabilities, but not their **lengths**...

Comment: It's not clear to me on what $v,A$ depend. But you could write A as a function of the elliptic integral ?

Comment: v and A naturally shouldn't depend on the perimeter of the ellipse if that's what you're thinking. I imagine they should depend on eccentricity, and minor/major radii. Maybe pi or e.